# EntityFramework - Detecting database scheme changes manually at production

Tags: entity-framework

Question is about: EntityFramework 6 CODE FIRST, Sql Server 2012

How can i detect that database schema changed and not compatible with current EF model?

I'm talking about production server and application. Default initializer is 'null', and it doen't update production database automatically, of course.

But if database schema changes, and no more compatible with my model, i want application must detect it on program startup. It is possible to do it manually.

If i'm not wrong, EntityFramework stores current schema on the __MigrationHistory table, and verifies it on the first context related operation, but not with 'null' initializer. From this reason, I want to do it manually on application startup.

I assume EntityFramework has related functions, i hope they are not private and i can use them.

(I have a problem caused by manual database schema change on one of our clients today)

Update: In fact, database schema changes occured by running same applications update tsql script, but applications itself is not updated.

Comment: Even with the null initializer there is a check for compatibility. In this case, on fail, you receive an exception.

Comment: In this case that problem caused by another problem.

Comment: -1 Simple quick check of the msdn docs yielded [`DbContext.Database.CompatibleWithModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: If you posted it as a answer i will accept it answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom initializer to accomplish this task.

```
public class ValidateDatabase<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
  public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
  {
    if (!context.Database.Exists())
    {
      throw new ConfigurationException( "Database does not exist");
    }
    else
    {
      if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
      {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The database is not compatible with the entity model.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```